# How to Insert Select from last table auto increment Id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have two tables as below:
[image]
I need to insert some data by a `store procedure` as below code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeviceInvoiceInsert]
@dt AS DeviceInvoiceArray READONLY
AS
DECLARE @customerDeviceId BIGINT
DECLARE @customerId BIGINT
DECLARE @filterChangeDate DATE
BEGIN
SET @customerId = (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerId FROM @dt WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL)
SET @filterChangeDate = (SELECT TOP 1 filterChangeDate FROM @dt)

INSERT INTO CustomerDevice
(customerId, deviceId, deviceBuyDate, devicePrice)
SELECT customerId,deviceId,deviceBuyDate,devicePrice FROM @dt 
WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL
SET @customerDeviceId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO FilterChange
(customerId, filterId, customerDeviceId, filterChangeDate)
SELECT @customerId,dt.filterId,@customerDeviceId,@filterChangeDate FROM @dt AS dt
END
```

**The problem is that when the procedure wants to insert data into the `FilterChange` table, the `@customerDeviceId` always has the last IDENTITY Id.**

how can I figure out this problem?

Comment: When you are inserting into `CustomerDevice`, your `SELECT` has a filter: `WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL`.  When you are inserting into `FilterChange`, there's no filter.  As a result, some of the `@dt` rows get inserted into `CustomerDevice` and receive a `CustomerDeviceId`, while the others remain without one.  So the question is, what should the `FilterChange` insert pass as `CustomerDeviceId` for those rows that were not inserted into `CustomerDevice` (and therefore don't have a corresponding ID value)?  Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Duplicate post of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277743/how-to-insert-select-from-last-table-auto-increment-id).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are searching for SET IDENTITY_INSERT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

So before insert statement:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT sometableWithIdentity ON

/*insert*/

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sometableWithIdentity OFF
```